# search for files with GUI

Tags: gui, search

I would like to search for a file with GUI. I have 2 files :

```
/world/europe/georgia_and-its_capital-tbilisi.info
/world/north_americas/usa/georgia_state_capital.info ;
```

A search for:

```
find /world -name "*gia*capit*"
```

-- brings up the two files.

How to conduct this search with Nautilus' search or any alternate suggestion? I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  And `Applications | Search` is not available on it.

Answer (score 5):

- You need Synaptic package manager to be installed.
- Within Synaptic  type  **gnome-search** in little quick search window.
- Then navigate to **gnome-search-tool**, select it for installation and install. 
  That's it.

Comment: You can also install it with `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool`. When I do this in Linux Mint it shows up in my start menu under "Accessories" as "Search for Files...". This is such a great tool! Works awesome.

Comment: seems like it doesn`t exist in apt in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I used it in Linux Mint 18.3, it works great.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find a file in your file system, I suggest you to use "Catfish file search". You can also use advanced settings, like file type, modified time and "special characters" like * or ?, as you mentioned in your question (*gia*capit*).

Catfish is a search GUI powered by locate and find behind the scenes, with autocompletion from Zeitgeist and locate.The interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only GTK+.

You can install it from the universe/utils repository using:

### Command line:

`sudo apt-get install catfish`

### Ubuntu Software Center:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/catfish/

Comment: catfish seems really buggy and has no features, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1085246/34298

Answer (score 1):

AFAIKT Ubuntu Dash does not suggest files outside of your Home.

- For all files in your home, use *`Meta`-f rt-of-fil* to find a file with name *part-of-file*. Where Meta, is your Windows-key, most probably.
- For everything else, you could use `find`, but if you want a GUI install *gnome desktop helpers*, it includes a *gnome-search-tool*, which is a GUI around `find`.

Comment: > install gnome desktop helpers  -- How to install 'gnome desktop helpers', and how to use ENTER key while posting a comment. Right now when I press the ENTER key, it posts the comment rather than starting a new line in the comment.

Comment: [Here is how a nice illustrated guide on how to install](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html). In there, search for _gnome-search-tool_. 

And enter? [shift][enter] has always worked, in most OSes since the early days. But stack-exchange comments ignore these white-spaces in comments.

Comment: The guide suggests that we launch: Ubuntu Software Center icon in the launcher, but how to get to that icon in 12.04; I do not see it. I see 'Ubuntu One' which comes close to sounding like 'Software Center' but it seems to be about Ubuntu Cloud. 

Is the help offered on this forum geared more towards the hoary Gnome Shell; if so, I might want to install it. Having never used it (and being a new linux user) I do not miss it.

Comment: You seem to have modified your ubuntu, or installed something else alltogether. This means you should first solve the issues around being able to install, before asking what to install.

Answer (score 0):

[Gnome Do](http://do.cooperteam.net/) is a pretty good tool. And with its plugins you can customise the directories/files you want to scan to a high degree.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "Search for Files" facility within Nautilus,  under the GO menu..  works beautifully

Comment: It's a system wide search, the default nautilus don't do that normally.