# ubuntu file search in thunar

Tags: thunar

In Ubuntu 18.4 I use the filebrowser `thunar` instead of the low-functionally internal filebrowser (`nautilus`), but there seems to be no button to search in folder.

I also added a custom action like described [here](https://fransdejonge.com/2017/10/adding-search-in-folder-to-thunar-custom-actions/), but that button isn't visible nowhere either.

How do I search inside the currently visible folder in thunar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Xubuntu 18.04

I don't use Xubuntu much but the little magnifying glass is under `File` in Thunar 1.6.15 and works without any further steps:

[image: Thunar Search]

---

## Ubuntu 18.04

One has to install `thunar` and `catfish`. Even after installing `catfish`, the search option doesn't appear.

To fix this,

- open `Edit` > `Configure custom actions`
- Click on the `+` sign to open a new child window
- In the tab titled `Basic`, enter `Search for files` in the Name box
- In the `Command` box, enter `catfish --path=%f` or choose something from the command parameters provided

Then open the `Appearance Conditions` tab. In there, enter `*` as the File Pattern and tick the appropriate choice below `Appears if selection contains:`

Click `OK`. Close the `Custom Actions` window.

The next time you open Thunar, you should see the option to `Search for files` when you click on `File` in Thunar's menu bar.

[image: Search]

More reading: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions

---

Edits:

- I've noticed a couple of cases in which Catfish didn't list all the relevant files. This was both in Xubuntu and Ubuntu. I'll make a separate question about that.
- As [rubo77 suggested in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085224/ubuntu-file-search-in-thunar/1085246#comment1785392_1085246), `searchmonkey` is a suitable alternative.

Comment: cool that works, although catfish seems a bit lacking of functionality. for example "open containing folder" would be nice. And then sure, your bug: did you report it upstream?

Comment: I tried `apt install searchmonkey` and added this line instead: `searchmonkey -d %f` works fine ;)

Comment: You should extract the part that explains the bug in catfish into a separate question with a new title, for example: "Why is catfish not showinf all files?" and then just link to that question here when you suggest catfish. (you can suggest searchmonkey as  an alternative here too)

Comment: I've edited the answer. I'll post about the missing files later today,

Comment: Worked perfectly.  The lack of this function has bugged me for years.